# Implement R2 From Scratch Problems

Tags: regression

I am trying to implement OLS regression from scratch, and scoring that model using R2 built from scratch (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares). I am expecting a model performance of 0.74 (that is, an R2 value), but my R2 result is way off.

```
 #data
 boston = load_boston()
 # obtain the feature matrix as a numpy array
 X = boston.data
 #obtain the target variable as a numpy array
 y = boston.target


#Append 1's for the intercept to the X matrix. 
ones = np.ones(shape=y.shape)[..., None]
X = np.concatenate((ones, X), 1)

#COMPUTE BETAS for regression. 
betas = inv(X.transpose().dot(X)).dot(X.transpose()).dot(y)

#remove intercept from X2 matrix, compute yhat. 
X2 = np.delete(X,0, axis=1)
y_hat = X2.dot(betas[:-1])

#Compute R2
errors = y - y_hat 
sse = (errors ** 2).sum()
tss = ((y - y.mean()) ** 2).sum()    
r2 = 1 - sse / tss
print("r2" , r2)

#output
r2 -2346.8284726742468
```

The R2 output makes no sense. Here is what it is supposed to look like when using one of Pythons packages:

```
# Using LinearRegression() to compute the regression
reg = LinearRegression()
# Fitting training data
reg = reg.fit(X2, y)
# Calculating R2 Score
r2_score = reg.score(X2, y)
print("r2_Score", r2_score)

#output 
r2_Score 0.7406077428649428
```

I suspect my mistake might be in matrix multiplication, but I've been looking at this for hours and have not spotted my error. The shapes are as follows:

```
print("X2",X2.shape)
print("betas",betas[:-1].shape)

#output
(506, 13)
(13,)
```

Any advice is truly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you attempt to compute the predictions without including the fitted intercept?  Why don't you ever use `params` after you initialize it?

Comment: I deleted that part. I had an idea to store the coefficients and intercept as keys in a dictionary but that just confuses things.

Comment: The important question was why don't you use the intercept?  You really need to *explain* what you're trying to do.  Without a clear explicit explanation all we have is two pieces of code that produce different output but little idea of what you *intend* each piece to do.  Please state your model, at least.

Comment: You mean when I am computing y_hat?

Comment: Of course.  Have you plotted your predictions and your actual data to check whether they're even close?